# Help in finding where proof breaks down

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose V is a real inner product space and $T \in L(v)$. Then T is self-adjoint if and only if $<Tv,v> \in \mathbb{R}$ for every $v \in V$

Above statement is clearly wrong since inner product of <Tv,v> on real inner product spaces are clearly real even if T isn’t self-adjoint

Need help finding in where the following proof is wrong:

If $<Tv,v> \in \mathbb{R}$,
Let $v \in V$, $<Tv,v>= <v,Tv> = <v,T^*v>$ and by Riesz representation theorem, $Tv=T^*v$ and thus T is self adjoint.

Comment: $(T^*v,v)=(Tv,v)\implies ((T^*-T)v,v)=0\quad \forall v\in V$. Note that it is not $((T^*-T)v,w)=0$ for every $w$ (and hence in particular for $w=(T^*-T)v$ thus giving $((T^*-T)v,(T^*-T)v)=0=||(T^*-T)v||$)

Answer (score 1):

You are assuming that $\langle (T-T^{*})v, v \rangle=0$ for all $v$  forces $T$ to be equal to $T^{*}$. This is false. For example, of $S$ is rotation by $90^{0}$ on $\mathbb R^{2}$ then $\langle Sv, v \rangle =0$ for all $v$ but $S \neq 0$.

Comment: I understand the above but Doesn't Riesz representation theorem allow me to not use the above since any linear functional can be represented by $<v,w>$ where w is unique and in particular to conclude that $Tv=T^*v$?

Comment: @Gnolius To conclude that $T=T^{*}$ you need $ \langle Tx, y \rangle= \langle T^{*}x, y \rangle$ for all $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Would $Tv=T^*v$ be insufficient to show that $<Tx,y>=<T^*x,y>$?

Comment: It is sufficient. But you don't have $Tv=T^{*}v$ in your case. @Gnolius

Comment: Ah okay, I got it now, thank you for your help, I think I confused<Tv,v> to be a linear functional by comparing it to <Tv,w> for fixed w

Comment: To draw that conclusion you need $\langle x, Tv \rangle=\langle x, T^{*}v \rangle$ **for all $x$**.